# Bounds for Szemerédi’s theorem for GAP’s

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, arithmetic-progression

Let a $(k,D)$-AP refer to sets of the form $\{n_0+l_1n_1+\dotsb +l_Dn_D: l_1,\dotsc,l_D \in [k]\}$ with cardinality $k^D$ (i.e. a proper $D$-dimensional GAP with width $k$).

Let $r(N,k,D)$ be the maximum cardinality of a set $A\subset [N]$ which contains no $(k,D)$-AP’s.

Obviously $r(N,k,1)$ is the well-studied quantity considered in Szemerédi’s Theorem. We have decent bounds for this quantity.

Meanwhile, it’s straightforward to show $$r(N,k,1)\le r(N,k,D) \le r(N,k^D,1).$$So plugging in the best  results for the $D=1$ case will give some bounds for $r(N,k,D)$.

I’m curious if any better bounds (in either direction) are known for some fixed $k,D$.

Comment: Because the key players in this question are written mathematically as $r(N,k,D)$, it's hard to google to see what's known previously about this quantity. You say it's well-studied. Maybe you could link to some places where the reader could learn more? My reasoning is that someone out there might know this quantity by some other name, and then could shed light on this question.